# Draw text ffmpeg does not end when the word ends

Tags: ffmpeg

It works very well. But it can not end the video while the text has run out. And it runs forever. The bottom is my code. It has gaps with the background image forever. I want to stop it when the text is over. please complete it help me.

```
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "C:\Users\Cu\Desktop\Lam\Lam\a.jpg" -i "C:\Users\Cu\Desktop\Lam\Lam\a.mp3" -vf drawtext='fontfile="Arial"\:style=bold:fontsize=70:textfile="C\:/Users/CuEm/Desktop/91990756.txt":fontcolor=#FFFFFF':x=0:y=h-20*t,format=yuv420p,scale=852x480,setsar=1:1  -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1000k -preset superfast "C:\Users\Cu\Desktop\b_o.mp4"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyw2w.jpg)

Comment: The text stops displaying half way through and you want it to continue the whole way?  anyway ffmpeg use questions are easier answered on superuser or AV than stackoverflow, FWIW.

Comment: oke thank you rogerdpack

Answer (score 0):

The drawtext filter has no concept of completion or progress. Assuming that you want the video to stop when the audio does, add `-shortest`.

Comment: "echo y | ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "C:\Users\CuEm\Desktop\Lam\Lam video a\a.jpg" -i "C:\Users\CuEm\Desktop\Lam\Lam video a\a.mp3" -vf drawtext='fontfile="Arial"\:style=bold:fontsize=70:textfile="C\:/Users/CuEm/Desktop/91067235.txt":fontcolor=#FFFFFF':x=0:y=h-(t+0.0)*24.0,format=yuv420p,scale=852x480,setsar=1:1 -t 559.0 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1000k -preset superfast "C:\Users\CuEm\Desktop\a_o.mp4"" I have a code like this but it calculates the wrong end speed. At the end of the video text is over. It still takes 2 to 3 minutes without text. Can you please me facebook please exchange me.Thank you